# Highcharts Angular - Highcharts Error #12

Tags: angular, typescript, api, highcharts, data-binding

I'm trying to show data in a line chart from this [API](https://bgpie.net/api/bgphistory/?peerAS=48821&peerIPAddress=2a07:a40::&prefix=2a0d:8d80::/32) with the 'date' values on the x-axis  and the 'announces' values on the y-axis. I get the [Highcharts Error #12](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/12/#:%7E:text=This%20error%20occurs%20if%20the,configurations%20to%20numbers%20or%20arrays) and the data doesn't show on the chart. I've structured the series.data property like this: `[[date, announces],[date, announces], ...]`. Here's my code:

```
dataChart: SequenceChartData[] = [];
bucketAnnouncements: Array<[Date, number]> = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartService.getSequenceChartData(this.data.peerAS, this.data.peerIPAddress, this.data.prefix)
    .subscribe((data: SequenceChartData[]) => {
      this.dataChart = data;
      this.update = true;
      this.show = true;
      let firstDay = Infinity;
      let lastDay = -Infinity;
      for (const val of this.dataChart){
        const date = moment.utc(val.date).unix();
        if (firstDay > date) {
          firstDay = date;
        }
        if (lastDay < date) {
          lastDay = date;
        }
      }
      for (let n = firstDay; n <= lastDay; n += 300) {
        this.bucketAnnouncements[n] = [
          new Date(n * 1000),
          0
        ];
      }
      for (const val of this.dataChart) {
        const date = val.date;
        this.bucketAnnouncements[moment.utc(date).unix()][1] = val.announces;
      }

      this.chartOptions.series = [
          {
            name: 'ao',
            type: 'line',
            data: this.bucketAnnouncements,
            color: '#009879',
          }
        ];
        });
    }
```

Using a `console.log` it seems that data is assigned correctly:

```
1546300800: (2) [Tue Jan 01 2019 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), 31]
1546301100: (2) [Tue Jan 01 2019 01:05:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), 30]
1546301400: (2) [Tue Jan 01 2019 01:10:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), 30]
1546301700: (2) [Tue Jan 01 2019 01:15:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), 30]
1546302000: (2) [Tue Jan 01 2019 01:20:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), 30]
1546302300: (2) [Tue Jan 01 2019 01:25:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), 30]
1546302600: (2) [Tue Jan 01 2019 01:30:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), 30]
...
```

I've also set the `turboTreshold` to higher numbers as suggested by the error but it still won't work (still gives the warning):

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        turboThreshold: 500000,
        ...
    }
}
```

For a more complete understanding of my code here is a [github repository](https://github.com/mauri5566/sitocopy/blob/master/src/app/components/sequences/modal-chart/modal-chart.component.ts) (couldn't resolve the merge conflicts)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the `date` format. 
For example, `Tue Jan 01 2019 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`) is not a number for the Highcharts. It's just a string. 
In order to solve this, use timestamps in milliseconds format.

There you might find some methods to convert it from one format to another. 
MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

put turboThreshold 0(Zero). It will work

plotOptions: {
series: {
turboThreshold: 0,
...
}
}